# How to reorder the elements in the vector according to the indexes given

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, element

I am trying to create a vector for the months such that the order of the months will start from the input of the mth + 1. (mth is the input)

For example, if the input, mth = 7, then the month in the vector will start from "August", then "september",.... (which is mth + 1, one month after the input).

Another example will be:

If the mth = 3, the vector for the months will be 
Month = c("April","September",......,"March")

What I am trying to do is automated the last line of my code, I had tried it but I had no idea how to continue.

```
year <- "2009"
mth <- "7"
day <- "1"

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(year,month,day))
df.date <- as.Date(with(df, paste(year,month,day,sep="-")),"%Y-%m-%d")

Month <- c("Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul")
```

I hope the code can help me to automate the Month according to the input of mth so that I no need to change it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using `head` and `tail` wrapped in a function `f`

```
f <- function(mth = 3) c(tail(month.abb, -mth), head(month.abb, mth))
f(3)
#[1] "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec" "Jan" "Feb" "Mar"
```

`month.abb` is one of the inbuilt R constants, giving a vector of all 3-letter months abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks jogo for the shorter code also, it helps me a lot and save my time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
mths = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
mth = 3

mths2 = c(mths[(mth+1):length(mths)],mths[1:mth])
> mths2
 [1] "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec" "Jan" "Feb" "Mar"
```

Comment: `mths[c((mth+1):length(mths), 1:mth)]` or `c(tail(mths, -mth), head(mths, mth))`